# In Mathematica, is there any elegant way to map over a list of variable names?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For example, the following rule to create a slider that edits a given variable:

```
EditorLine[stat_] := {
   Labeled[Slider[Dynamic[stat], {1, 20, 1}],
   {SymbolName[Unevaluated[stat]]}, {Left}], Dynamic[stat]}
SetAttributes[EditorLine, HoldFirst]
```

This works fine for `EditorLine[x]`, but using a map - e.g., `EditorLine /@ {x,y,z}`, gives an error because the map function evaluates the variable names and thus they are not held.

This can be done by writing `EditorLine /@ {Unevaluated[x],Unevaluated[y],Unevaluated[z]}` but if I wanted to write repeated function calls like that I would not be using a map!

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work too:

```
EditorLine /@ Unevaluated[{x, y, z}]
```

and if you add `Listable` attribute, even shorter:

```
EditorLine[{x, y, z}]
```